# Upper bound for the sum of the multiplication of adjacent items of a list

Tags: inequality, optimization, upper-lower-bounds

If $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = X$, where $X$ is a positive constant and $\forall i, x_i$ is a positive integer, then what is the upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_i x_{i+1})$?

Intuitively, set $ x_1=\dots=x_n=\frac {X}{n}$, and then we obtain the maximum?

Comment: What have you tried? Lagrange multipliers seems like a good starting point.

Comment: Nope. For $n=3$ the maximum is when $x_{1}=x_{3}=\frac{X}{4}$ and $x_{2}=\frac{X}{2}$. In the sum of products, $x_{2}$ appears twice, so it makes sense that it needs to be bigger than the other two